# Can I create a windows print queue that works like dev/null?

Tags: windows, printing

I want to create a windows print queue where all jobs added to that queue simply vanish.  They don't print, they don't accumulate... they just quietly go away.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have it connected to `NUL:`.

Comment: I can attach a printer to all sorts of ports. `NUL` is not an option, though.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't handled printers on Windows in a while, but there has to be some way you can add it as a port.

Comment: @Joey: You just have to add `NUL:` as a port.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this microsoft Technet [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782436%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create a fake printer whether you want to delete the jobs or you want to save them in your disk(for some reasons), and other port options as well

Comment: Can you summarise the important information from the Technet article?